# Project structure in rust -- adding extra files

Tags: rust

I am learning rust and am super confused at the project structure for cargo projects. I am using this [page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html) (and the rust book) for reference.

I am trying to separate my project for different structs so they can have their own file, similar to cpp and classes.

so if I have

```
src/main.rs
src/struct_name.rs
```

and I create the mod for it:

```
pub mod struct_name
{
    pub struct _struct_name
    {}
}
```

I should be able to do this in main.rs:

```
mod struct_name;
```

But the problem I am having is when I am trying to include external crates. For example, I'm trying to implement clap and use macros. So I do the following in igloo.rs:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate clap;
use clap::{Arg, App};

pub mod struct_name
{
    pub struct _struct_name
    {//do clap things}
}
```

I am given the error E0468 "an 'extern crate' loading macros must be at the crate root". Does this mean I can never use macros outside of main.rs or lib.rs? How can I somehow export these functions so that I can use them in struct_name.rs? I get that I could make export functions in main.rs or lib.rs, but if I am using the mod in main.rs and lib.rs, then struct_name.rs would never see the exported functions, right?

Answer (score 1):

In main.rs:
Macros imported at the top of the crate are avaliable everywhere in the crate.

```
    #[macro_use]
    extern crate clap;
    mod struct_name
```

In struct_name.rs:
You only need to define a module in its parent.

```
    use clap::{Arg, App};
    // do things
```